# Swift : Color Changing SKSpriteNode on repeat

Tags: swift, animation, skspritenode, skaction

I want to change the color of my SKSpriteNode similar to a strobe light how it constant changes colors then repeats. I can do it with a UIView like this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0.0, options:[UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat, UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse], animations: {
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}, completion: nil)
```

but i want to do it to a sksprite node. I did something like this and created a bunch of them but it was problematic, and i feel there might be a better way.

```
let changeBlue = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(UIColor.blueColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 2.0)
self.runAction(changeBlue)

let changeRed = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(UIColor.redColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 2.0)
self.runAction(changeRed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for `sequence(_:)`. See [Creating Actions That Combine or Repeat Other Actions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/sequence:) in the `SKAction` docs. Also, `repeatActionForever(_:)` to make the action repeat indefinitely.

```
let colorBlue = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(UIColor.blueColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 2.0)
let colorRed = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(UIColor.redColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 2.0)
let colorizeSequence = SKAction.sequence([colorBlue, colorRed])
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(colorizeSequence))
```

Comment: You're amazing! Thank you sir